# showing each single image of products in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have double tables one for products and one for files, files table have multi images related to the one product.

I want to show only one image for each product not all of them.

I make this code but it's back with the for example 3 times with the first image!

```
@foreach($lastProducts as $key => $lastProduct)
@if($key == 1)
<div class="bl-thumb">
<img src="{{url('website/'.$lastProduct->path.$lastProduct->->file}}">
</div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

I need to show the first image at my page and other pages show the second and third image for the product.

And here's my view which want to show all images on it :

```
<div class="slim-scroll">
    <div class="item active">
        <a href="" title="" data-lg-img="/website/images/{{$product->image_1}}" class="pic"><img src="/website/images/{{$product->image_1}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-lg-img="/website/images/{{$product->image_2}}" class="pic"><img src="/website/images/{{$product->image_2}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-lg-img="/website/images/{{$product->image_3}}" class="pic"><img src="/website/images/{{$product->image_3}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" data-lg-img="/website/images/{{$product->image_4}}" class="pic"><img src="/website/images/{{$product->image_4}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's showing me something like that without the foreach

[image]
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I need to get the first image only , it doesn't .  It gives me 3 images not one

Comment: Isn't that what you are trying to do with the foreach loop

Comment: Yes but it working wrong with me , I have for Product_id  ( three diffrent images )  , i want to get each one as a single image  ( first and second and third ) , by the above code , it's back with the first image 3 times !

Comment: can you do a **`{{ dd ($lastProducts) }}`** and post in your question

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: So are you getting **`71481490601138.jpg`** three times, using the **`@foreach($lastProducts as $key => $lastProduct)`** loop?

Comment: Yes , i need each one as single image showing to me , not the first image back three times

Comment: Have you tried removing the **`@if($key == 1)`** check within the foreach loop

Comment: removing  it back to me with the all three images , the all array , and that not also what i need

Comment: In your foreach loop there is **`$lastProduct->->file`** Is this a typo or is actually in your code?

Comment: No i have fixed it , my code onley one ->

Comment: Within your @foreach loop can you echo out the value of $key outside the if check

Comment: sorry,how can i do that

Comment: `@foreach ($lastproducts as $key => $product)
{{ $key }}
@endforeach`

Comment: It give me  0,1,2

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple products and each product has multiple images. If on page 1 you want to display product 1 image 1, product 2 image 1, product 3 image 1...then on page 2 you want to display product 1 image 2, product 2 image 2, product 3 image 2 you could try something like this:

Page 1:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <div class="bl-thumb">
      <img src="{{url('website/' . $product->images->pull('1')->path . $product->images->pull('1')->file}}">
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Page 2:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <div class="bl-thumb">
      <img src="{{url('website/' . $product->images->pull('2')->path . $product->images->pull('2')->file}}">
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Really this logic should be in the controller though. You could use a get variable to define what page you are on and filter for the proper image before you render the page.

Comment: No , It's only one product and have multi images , but on single product page will show all images for that product , and on allproduct page will show only the first image for that product